# My project is Online Exam.On next button of jsp next question gets displayed .Issue is timer getting resert after every next button

Tags: jsp, timer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function counter(secs,elem)
{
    var element=document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML="Hi"+secs+"";
    if(secs < 1)
        {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        element.innerHTML="<h2>Countdowm</h2>";

        }
    secs=secs-1;
    var timer=setTimeout('counter('+ secs +',"'+elem+'")',1000);

    }
</script>

<div id="demo"></div>
<script >counter(10,"demo");</script>
```

My timer getting reset after every next button of jsp.
My project is online examination system on next button same jsp page displays next question but timer getting reset after every question.

Comment: because maybe your page refresh , every time when button is clicked . Try to use `ajax` , it will prevent page refresh.

Comment: I dont know much about ajax will you please help me for that

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax) out.